# Airports with longest continuous temperature records

Tags: temperature

Does anyone have a resource on what airports (or other recording stations) have been recording temperature continuously (daily) for quite a while?

I remember reading that some back to the 1910s/1920s, but I am having trouble finding resources on which airports, and of course getting my hands on the records themselves. I would like very much to find such resources.

Comment: Something to consider: The areas around most all airports has had extensive development , so they will show a strong" Heat island" affect, temperatures will be higher now than in the past. I am familiar with Chicago- Ohare , ORD - for the orchard it was before WW2. Even in 1960 it was rural, Today it is in the midst of urban sprawl.

Comment: There's probably simpler sites to answer it.  But you can certainly check how long observations have been taken at various sites in the US by going through NOAA [NOWDATA](http://sercc.com/nowdata.html) (click the office, choose your site, and then click the calendar and see what the first year is)... for quick example, New York Central Park goes back to 1869.  Note though that of course the instrument setups have changed, and all were once recorded manually, so it could be possible there is some variation in the data in addition to any possible local and global shifts.

Comment: Also, you are very unlikely to find records from airports that are more than a century old, since there weren't that many airplanes around.  But if you search for "oldest continuous temperature record" you find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_England_temperature which predates airports by a couple of centuries.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty easy-to-digest resource from NOAA here:

ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-history.csv

It has a list of temperature sources (including airports), with their start/end dates that they were measuring.